# AJAX long requests

Tags: ajax, database

I will save data with AJAX, but due to the long request I encountered the following error

> Request-URI Too Large
>
> The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

What do I need to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the URL is too long because of folder structure, try using Mod_rewrite (If the server runs on Apache) to shorten it.

If it is because you are sending too many **GET** variables (most likely), send them via **POST** and it will be fixed

Comment: What error did you get when using POST? Still the same? Can you post the URL where you are sending the request? (Or at least it's length)